# FFmpeg: calculate time to convert images and .mp3 to a video

Tags: image, video, ffmpeg

Is there any formula that I can use to calculate the time that FFmpeg uses to convert a single .jpg image and .mp3 song to a video?

I am using the following code:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -r ntsc -i image.jpg -i song.mp3 -c:a copy -c:v libx264 \
  -preset fast -threads 0 -shortest
```

Lets say we have an image with X resolution and .mp3 length of L. Would the formula be:

```
time = X * L(in seconds) ?
```

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-r 1`, it is faster

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -r 1 -i image.jpg -i song.mp3 -c:a copy -c:v libx264 \
  -preset fast -threads 0 -shortest
```

[`ref`](http://github.com/svnpenn/a/blob/master/ff-audio.sh)

Comment: Thank you for this Steven. Could you explain what does the parameter -r 1? Also, do you have any clue on how to calculate the time the process will take to finish with the coding? 

Thank you for help

Comment: r stands for 'bit rate'

Comment: Should be be `-framerate`, not `-r` as dictated by the [image muxer documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1).

Answer (score 3):

First, run benchmark with key "-t 10" this mean 10 seconds benchmark and calculate run time.

```
ffmpeg -i .......... -t 10 -f null - -benchmark
```

Benchmark output, with  runtime: **utime**:

```
bench: utime=3.203s
bench: maxrss=215036kB
[aac @ 0000026cb6474600] Qavg: 1569.054
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]
**First Of All Call this method from OnProgress Method of FFmpeg Listener**

```
 public void onProgress(String s) {
            getProgress(s);
            Log.e("Editor", "String ==== " + s);
    }
```

*getProgress(s) is a method that find Estimate Time of Our execution*

```
 private void getProgress(String message) {
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("time=([\\d\\w:]{8}[\\w.][\\d]+)");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(message);
            matcher.find();
            String tempTime = String.valueOf(matcher.group(1));
            Log.d(TAG, "getProgress: tempTime " + tempTime);
            String[] arrayTime = tempTime.split("[:|.]");
            long currentTime =
                    TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(Long.parseLong(arrayTime[0]))
                            + TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(Long.parseLong(arrayTime[1]))
                            + TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(Long.parseLong(arrayTime[2]))
                            + Long.parseLong(arrayTime[3]);

            String speed;
            speed = message.substring(message.indexOf("speed=") + 1, message.indexOf("x")).split("=")[1];

            long percent = 100 * currentTime / videoLengthInMillis;
            long time = TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(Long.parseLong(arrayTime[0])) * 3600 + TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(Long.parseLong(arrayTime[1])) * 60 + TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(Long.parseLong(arrayTime[2])) + Math.round(Long.parseLong(arrayTime[3]));
            long ETA = Math.round((Math.round(videoLengthInMillis) - time) / Float.valueOf(speed));
            Log.e(TAG, "currentTime -> " + currentTime + "s % -> " + percent);
            Log.e(TAG, "ETA -> " + ETA);

            progressBar.setProgress((int) percent);
            String EstimateTime = convertSecondsToHMmSs(ETA);
            Log.e(TAG, "EstimateTime -> " + EstimateTime);
            ProcessTime.setText(EstimateTime);
        }
```

*ConvertSecondToHMmSs*

```
public static String convertSecondsToHMmSs(long millis) {

    long seconds=(millis/1000);
    long s = seconds % 60;
    long m = (seconds / 60) % 60;
    long h = (seconds / (60 * 60)) % 24;
    return String.format("%d:%02d:%02d", h,m,s);
}
```