# FFmpeg - calculate the remaining conversion time

Tags: video, ffmpeg, converters

I use ffmpeg to convert a clip video.mp4 to video.mp3 for example.
Is there a way to calculate the remaining conversion time ?

Comment: No. If you know the duration of the output, you can calculate `( total duration - processed duration ) / current speed`, but this is logically unsound.

Comment: Surely, an estimate based on the size of input files, and rate at which they are consumed would be a good estimate. It makes no sense to consider the output side.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15831197/ffmpeg-calculate-time-to-convert-images-and-mp3-to-a-video/52627198#52627198

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working logic I copied from other pages and modified it to not throw exception while matcher is trying to find speed pattern, also removed unnecessary assignments and made a more dynamic toTimer conversion. And of course I've tested myself, so everything are good to go.

```
public String getRemainingTime(String message, long videoLengthInMillis) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("time=([\\d\\w:]{8}[\\w.][\\d]+)");
    if (message.contains("speed")) {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(message);
        @SuppressWarnings("UnusedAssignment")
        String tempTime = "";
        if (matcher.find()) {
            tempTime = String.valueOf(matcher.group(1));
            String[] arrayTime = tempTime.split("[:|.]");
            long time =
                    TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(Long.parseLong(arrayTime[0])) +
                            TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(Long.parseLong(arrayTime[1])) +
                            TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(Long.parseLong(arrayTime[2])) +
                            Math.round(Long.parseLong(arrayTime[3]));
            String speed = message.substring(message.indexOf("speed=") + 1, message.indexOf("x")).split("=")[1];
            long eta = Math.round((Math.round(videoLengthInMillis) - time) / Float.valueOf(speed));
            String estimatedTime = toTimer(eta);
            Log.d("getRemainingTime", "EstimateTime -> " + estimatedTime);
            return estimatedTime;
        }
    }
    return "";
}
private String toTimer(long millis) {
    long hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis);
    long minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) -
            TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis));
    long seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) -
            TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis));
    if (hours!= 0 && hours>0)
        return String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d:%02d",hours,minutes,seconds);
    else
        return String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d",minutes,seconds);
}
```

Use it inside FFmpeg `onProgress` callback:

```
@Override
public void onProgress(String message) {
    String remainingTime = getRemainingTime(message,yourVideoDurationInMilliseconds);
    Log.d("onProgress", "Remaining Time: "+remainingTime);
}
```